# Is the realm of sets belonging to weakly reachable from below stages of the cumulative heirarchy a model of ZF?

Tags: set-theory

I want to know how high is the universe of sets in ZFC as seen from below.

We say that a stage $V_\alpha$ of the cumulative hierarchy is reachable from below if and only if $\alpha$ is isomorphic to an ordering on a set that belongs to a prior stage. Formally:

$\text{reachable} (V_\alpha) \iff \exists S \in V_\alpha \exists f \exists \mathcal R \\ [ f: \alpha \hookrightarrow S  \land \forall \beta,\gamma \in \alpha \ (\beta < \gamma \Leftrightarrow f(\beta) \ \mathcal R \ f(\gamma) )]$

Now we define *hierarchical gap* as a nonempty stage of the hierarchy that is not reachable from below.

Define: $\text{weakly-reachable} (V_\alpha) \iff |\{ V_{\beta <\alpha}| V_\beta \text { is hierarchical gap } \}| < |V_\alpha|$

A stage is hereditarily weakly-reachable from below if it and every stage prior to it is weakly-reachable from below.

> Does the realm of all sets beloning to hereditarily weakly-reachable from below stages constitute a model of ZF? Or ZF can prove the existence of a non weakly-reachable stage from below?

If we redefine weak reachability as:

$\text{weakly reachable} (V_\alpha) \iff |\{ V_{\beta <\alpha}| V_\beta \text { is hierarchical gap } \}| < |\alpha| $

> Can ZF prove existence of a non weakly reachable stage?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of reachable. If $f$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, then every relation on $X$ can be translated to a relation on $Y$. All you say is that $|S|=|\alpha|$. So unreachable is simply $V_\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is not smaller than any $x\in V_\alpha$. These are exactly the fixed points of the strong limit cardinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that there are **lots** of non weakly reachable stages, even according to the stronger definition. In fact, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that the class of indices of such stages is a club.

---

The key point is that the indices of levels of $V$ which are not reachable from below form a club (this is easiest to see if we use a simpler definition of reachability: $V_\alpha$ is reachable from below iff $\alpha$ is in bijection with some $S\in V_\alpha$). To see this, think about iterating the function $$\xi\mapsto\sup\{\aleph^*(V_\zeta): \zeta<\xi\}.$$

Now $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves$^*$ that, given **any** club $C$, there is some ordinal $\theta\in C$ such that $\theta\cap C$ has ordertype $\theta$; this is a standard exercise. Applying this to the club of indices of non-reachable-from-below levels of $V$ gives the desired result for the second sense of weak reachability; for the first sense, just consider the intersection of $C$ with the club of ordinals satisfying $\vert\alpha\vert=\vert V_\alpha\vert$.

And in fact this really shows that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that there is a club of such ordinals.

---

$^*$Strictly speaking, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves a theorem *scheme*: for each formula $\varphi$, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves "If $\varphi$ defines a club of ordinals, then there is some ordinal $\theta$ such that $\varphi(\theta)$ and the set of ordinals $<\theta$ satisfying $\varphi$ has ordertype $\theta$."

Comment: What's the fixed point if $V_\xi$ is not well-ordered? You want to actually map $\xi$ to the Lindenbaum of $V_\xi$, and then take a limit. Or if you want to be *continuous*, which you seem to want (for a good reason), just take $\xi\mapsto\sup\{\aleph^*(V_\zeta)\mid\zeta<\xi\}$ instead.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Whoops, fixed!

Comment: what is the ordinal index of the smallest non weakly-reachable stage in ZF called?